# MultiValueDictKeyError at /main/add at 'num1'

Tags: python, django, dictionary

From below Coded project i want to add two numbers and want to print their resultant value. All things goes smoothly but when i try to print the resultant value it make me causes a "MultiValueDictKeyError" errors. I have searched and tried so many ways but failed to resolve the problem.

**The project tree look like this**
[project files tress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ueg7.png)

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

def home(request):
return render(request, 'base.html')

@csrf_exempt
def add(request):

   val1 = int(request.POST['num1'])
   val2 = int(request.POST['num2'])
   res = val1 + val2

return render(request, "main/index.html", {'add_result': res})
```

**Index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h3>This two number adding form</h3>

<form action="{% url 'add' %}" method="POST">
    Enter the first here: <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="First Number"><br>
    Enter the second here: <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<hr>

<div>
    Result : <p>{{ add_result }} </p>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, 
 minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>ADDTWONUMBER</title>
</head>
<body>

<H4>THIS IS FORM OF ADDING TWO NUMBER</H4>
<li><a href="main/add">click here to add two number</a></li>
<div>
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
path('main/add' , views.add, name = 'add'),
]
```

**Errors**

```
> MultiValueDictKeyError at /main/add
> 'num1'
> Request Method:   GET
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/add
> Django Version:   3.0.4
> Exception Type:   MultiValueDictKeyError
> Exception Value:  'num1'
> Exception Location:   /home/hudacse6/Env/lib/python3.7/site- 
  packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 78
> Python Executable:    /home/hudacse6/Env/bin/python
> Python Version:   3.7.4
> Python Path:  
 ['/home/hudacse6/pr1_todoapps',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/hudacse6/Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
> Server time:  Wed, 18 Mar 2020 17:09:20 +0000
```

[Error in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du04u.png)

How to do dealt with this error?

Comment: The return statements aren't correctly indented in views.py, are they in the real code ?

Comment: i just copy and paste all of my code. if it is about correctly indented or not, then Pycharm Pro will automatically solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `get()` method on `request.POST` ?

```
val1 = int(request.POST.get('num1', None))
val2 = int(request.POST.get('num2', None))
```

Comment: let me try this one.

Comment: get the error: 

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'